# Fetch data from website real time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, curl, fetch

Ok basically i'm fetching data from website using curl and parsing the contents using CkHtmlToText.

My issue is how to fetch new data website is writing down.

For example website contents are as follow:

-test1
-test2

After 1 second contents are :
-test1
-test2
-test3

How to fetch only the next line website wrote down that i didnt get yet which is " test3".

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Language im using is : Visual c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP requests are stateless. You make a request, you get a result, then you make another completely independent request, you get another result, and so on. If the resource you are trying to access is changing over time, you need to make multiple requests, where each time you will get the full updated resource.

I imagine you may be describing a web page that automatically updates while you are looking at it (like a Twitter feed, for example). In that case, the response contains a script that allows the browser to fetch new data and inject it into the DOM. Unless you also plan to build the DOM and use a JavaScript engine (basically implementing a web browser) to run the script, this is probably not useful to you. Instead, you are better off finding an API that gives you data in a format that is easy to parse and get updates for. If this API is a REST API (built on HTTP), then you will still need to make independent requests to get updates.

Comment: The website is writing down chat messages and i want to fetch new chat lines appearing.So you think i still need to make independent requests or is there any existing  function in curl or any other library that can do the job?

Comment: @juniorcoder Is the chat updating as you look at it? If so, you need to find out what the script is doing to fetch new messages and maybe you can do the same.

Comment: @juniorcoder In which case you need to request the full page, just like refreshing in your browser will do.

Comment: mmm i see , any idea how can i filter it after next request to display the only needed chat ?

Comment: @juniorcoder You could maybe do a diff of the pages, depending on how it is formatted. Otherwise you're going to have to parse the result somehow. If you are the developer of the chat web page, there's no reason you couldn't support a GET parameter that specifies the last read message and only returns newer ones.